# LG L3 : difference between system memory and internal memory

Tags: internal-storage, ram

I'm using LG L3 E405, and when I see memory usage in App Manager. I see there three sections: First is system memory (just about 200M), second is internal memory (1 GB) and last is my sd card (8GB).

I know difference between internal memory (is internal sd card) and normal sd card. But I don't know purpose of system memory. It's too low, and often applications are installed to there. After install, I must move those apps again to internal memory, but not all I can do this.

Please help me figure out this point.

Comment: Internal memory is the actual RAM "chip" (for want of better word, technically integrated within the CPU) itself. System "*memory*" is a partition in which the Android OS resides in (note how I emphasized memory in context of system!)

Comment: Isn't system memory a memory where Android OS is installed? Internal memory is where the apps are installed (or necessary files are linked). SD card gets the secondary storage.

Answer (score -1):

You better go to Cellshopes, get "Root" on your Adroid device, but it's too risky and oftentimes warranty will be voided once it happen.

Comment: -1 This doesn't answer the question.